# python: turning textwrap into a list

Tags: python

i have a variable:

```
row='saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050 symphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand cervera in 024 039 christophe guiot in 024 029 and thibault vieux violin soloists orchestre les archets de paris'
```

i am doing this:

```
textwrap.fill(row,55)
```

i would like some list `line` to have `line[0]='saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050'` and `line[1]='symphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand'` etc.....

please help me with this conversion from textwrap into a list

please note that textwrap breaks things up by `\n`

Comment: @jenny: don't just copypaste code, read answers, did you have a look at textwrap module as I suggested? What did you see there?

Comment: @jenny: You might enjoy looking at Doug Hellman's tour of `textwrap` in his excellent Python Module of the Week blog: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/textwrap/index.html#module-textwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `textwrap.wrap` instead of `textwrap.fill`

Answer (score 1):

[`textwrap.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) returns a list.  Why not use that?

`textwrap.fill(text, ...)` is the equivalent of `"\n".join(wrap(text, ...))`. As explained in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill).

Answer (score 1):

You can just [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it using e.g.

```
textwrap.fill(row, 55).split('\n')
```

or use `textwrap.wrap` instead.